Remapping Right-Alt key to Context Menu (Shift+F10)
On a fresh install of Ubuntu 24 on a 2012 MacBookPro, I followed the instructions in the link,
https://deskthority.net/viewtopic.php?t=24077
and successfully mapped three of my keys. But the forth, right alt to context menu, doesn't work and I cannot figure out why.
Here are the contents of my /etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb file.
evdev:input:b0003v05ACp0252e0111*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e3=leftctrl
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e0=leftmeta
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e7=rightctrl
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e6=menu

I've restarted to be sure, and evtest shows the mapping has taken, but the key isn't doing anything.
Any ideas?
